# Why are we deleting off-topic closed questions at all?

Tags: discussion, search, deleted-questions, off-topic

What is the benefit of deleting off-topic closed questions at all? What is wrong with the idea that they couldn't stay in closed state *forever*?

Closed question are searchable by the entire community (including newcomers). Deleted question [are searchable only by a selected group of users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Note that deleted posts do not normally appear in search results. To find questions you posted that are deleted, see the Deleted questions page (which is linked at the bottom of the Questions page of your user profile). In addition, users with the moderator tools privilege can search among their own deleted posts by using the search operator deleted:1 (site moderators can use this to find deleted posts by any user on the site).

So, the story goes like this:

1. A newcomer writes a question
2. It gets closed as off-topic
3. Closed question is deleted
4. A newcomer writes a question
5. Suggestion box does not show previously deleted question
6. Question gets closed as off-topic
7. Question is deleted.
8. Newcomer writes a question...

Why it could go like this:

1. A newcomer writes a question
2. It gets closed as off-topic
3. A newcomer writes a question
4. Suggestion box shows that a very similar question was previously marked as off-topic and closed
5. High chances that a newcomer won't write another question but rather clicks the previous one?

Based on above, I assume that deleting off-topic questions brings us *zero* value while keeping it closed forever brings us *at least some* value.

Since we're currently deleting off-topic closed questions, can someone clarify my assumption?

Comment: You're assuming that users who don't search first, take the tour, read the help pages, follow the advice in their new user question experience would respond favourably to one more bit to read or button to click in order to *'just post my damn question, will you!!!'* I love your faith in humanity ;)

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could underline in my question a sentence or paragraph based on which you have came to the conclusion that I am assuming all of that. Because I am not. All the time I am talking about the same thing. I am writing my question and it _above edit box_ a list of questions pops. I see that a very similar question was closed as off-topic. I stop asking. It maybe just me (hard to believe), a couple, a dozens or a hundreds, but still. When questions are deleted I won't see them at all above my edit box. Period. Nothing more. No, a totally _don't_ believe in humanity, sorry.

Comment: In my past ~10 years history, on all my 80+ sites, I could (for just myself) recall _a hundreds_ of such situations where I (just a _single_ user) refrained myself from asking, because I have noticed the very similar question being marked as off-topic. That "hundreds of situations" would be narrowed down to _zero_, if all those closed off-topic questions would be deleted.

Comment: All I'm seeing right now is a one-person campaign to be 'proven right'. Two consecutive questions in here which basically add up to the same thing & a fair bit of arguing with the mods in Movies. You don't seem to be quite getting the point that people don't actually have to agree with you, no matter how loud you shout. Sorry, but you need to take a step back from this & re-think.

Comment: [The other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386131/deleting-closed-off-topic-questions-and-the-post-ban) being referred to.

Answer (score 18):

Because leaving those questions around will not stop people from writing another similar question. This can commonly be seen with duplicate questions as you will see posters argue that their question is different. This is true even when you can copy and paste the accepted answer to answer their question.

There is no need to keep around bad questions that have been closed that will provide no value to users on the site. Keeping around old off topic questions doesn't mean that they will show up as related questions when someone else asks or that they will actually act upon that information.

Not to mention the longer a bad question stays around the more it will attract downvotes and have a larger impact on the person who asked it.

Comment: As I tried to explain in my question, I disagree with your first claim. I think that seeing such question (closed as off-topic) will stop at least some other users from posting. It will stop at least one of them -- me! :) Not seeing them at all (deleted) won't stop anyone. However, your last argument is a Jack Pot as for me. Thanks!

Comment: @trejder You are free to disagree with that claim all you want but that doesn't change the fact that people dispute a question is a duplicate even when the answer is an exact copy of the other question.

Answer (score 13):

### Most of what gets deleted isn't worth saving

I was wondering for quite some time what exactly was getting deleted, and as a moderator on several sites I was able to look into it myself.

Most of what's deleted on main sites wasn't deleted by a person but [automatically by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) (and it really helps to know what those rules are). Some questions are self deleted. And the remainder (a small amount on most sites) are deleted by either delete voters or moderators.

Another important aspect is that most questions that are deleted don't have answers, as much as 75%. Of those that do have answers, most answers score 0 or less. This is mostly because of how Community auto deletion works, and partially because the people with delete votes are usually invested enough in the site that they don't want to remove content for no reason.

Off topic questions without good answers don't solve people's problems, and when there were good answers they may become outdated. Furthermore, the presence of off topic questions can actually hurt because many people won't see or understand that the question is closed:

[image: best dictionary question shown when asking a question]

### You can prevent content you think is valuable from being deleted

It's very simple, and you barely need any privileges. Upvote good content. Easy and effective. (Again, this works because Community looks at votes before deleting.)

For something that's a little more high effort, you can work with authors to help improve their posts, ideally to the point where it is an on topic question that can be reopened. You may be able to help some along yourself by editing too.

And of course there are the privileges that are unlocked at higher rep levels (close/reopen votes, delete/undelete votes) that need no explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now, the most funny thing (at least to me) is that my deleted question managed to slip over most (if not all) of your assumptions given in this answer. It was: (a) manually deleted by a moderator, it has (had) an answer and this answer was 10+ upvoted. In addition: good answer that I received does solve my problem and it won't get out-dated (because it is about permanent, unchangeable thing). Also your proposal for salvaging question from deletion is wrong. You can't upvote your own question.

Comment: In other words, we have deleted a question 60 hours since it was closed (and it was closed even faster since asking) where those 60-100 hours was enough for an answer to such question to gain over 10 upvotes. In my personal opinion this violates the whole idea of sharing knowledge. By "sharing knowledge" we understand sharing answers, not questions. A very good answer (>10 votes in <100 hours) is now lost, because of some auto-ID-questions-swept policy. Sorry, for me this is wrong. But... someone said that there are no good answers to bad questions, so let's dig this whole case down, shall we?

Comment: You're still complaining essentially about being swept up in a global, "no more ID questions" policy. Your question is not coming back. You've already been told why by the mods [& others] of that site. You're trying to genericise a specific act. It's time to give up this campaign, really.

Comment: @trejder I can't really comment on why a moderator deleted the Q&A, since it didn't happen on my site and site policy can vary considerably. This answer was primarily written from a general perspective; when it's your own question you have all the tools and freedom to edit to fix it. It really sounds like you need to go to the site's meta to ask about it (if you haven't already taken the advice from the other question).

Comment: @Tetsujin I find deleting questions a completely wrong idea that benefits nothing and can cause a serious loss. Period. I thought I have made a clear declaration about my intentions at least a couple of times. Since your comment above is second complete misunderstanding of my intentions in just an hour (and you are using tone that suggests that you are 100% sure that you are correct) then the only thing that has left to me is really step down and end this discussion. No, you are completely wrong in your assumptions. Here and earlier. This has nothing to do with that single question. Period.

Comment: trejder - you are still hanging onto this one assumption that off-topic questions are worth keeping. The community quite clearly disagrees with you; exemplified in more than just this specific QA. You have raised four separate meta questions, two here & two on M&TV, all of which are defending the same point, mostly with great swathes of argument underneath in comments. Not one of them has a net positive vote. Your insistence on it not being specific to that one central point, I'm afraid does not really ring true.

Comment: The question you're complaining about hit HNQ, meaning many people not familiar with M&TV's site rules will have voted on it. HNQ always skews a question's 'true worth' to the site, as many more people see it than would normally. Even with the benefit of HNQ, it still only managed to scrape a +3 net vote. Time to let this one lie.

Answer (score 1):

I think I once had a post on one of the per-site metas that goes into depth on this, but while the extant answers here cover most of the better points here, one thing I want to bring up with is the very nature and intent of "close". There's a disconnect here which is what usually leads to a lot of this mindset of closing things to keep them around but that's not the design of how the Q&A network was built upon. Excluding duplicates as a special case (so special a case we took a few years to finally change the label on the title), closure is not meant as a preservative state, or even as a punitive state for that matter. It's meant as a *temporary state* used as a moderation tool for cleanup. Nothing more, nothing less.

Things are closed because they're suspect of not belonging on the site. There's a myriad of reasons this is provided - the question is of too low quality to comprehend as an actual question, the question's scope is too broad to be properly solved by answerers, or the topic of current being that the question literally doesn't belong on the site because it's off-topic. Closure is a sentence to deletion and exists as an appeal period where users can attempt to defend it as actually belonging on the site. This is often done by editing the question to actually fit on the site where possible. If this doesn't happen then after a few days the post is able to be deleted, and ideally reaches that fate. This is once again not meant to be punitive (on its own, barring the propagation of continuing the behavior) - once deleted, there's no more immediately public artifact of the incident so a user who innocently made a mistake once can just move on without some tag of shame in their history for people to dwell on. Works just like when you ask a question yourself, realize it's pretty stupid, and self-delete it for not even being a real question.

So questions never intend to stay closed. Either they get fixed and reopened (and everyone is happy), or they get deleted (and no one has to feel bad).

I distinctly remember calling the opposite something akin to putting heads on pikes. You keep closed questions as a "warning". But there's reasons this doesn't work for us. It makes people feel bad because now you're a warning, when site rules already exist to demonstrate what does or does not belong without making an example out of people. It also implies this "If you do this you will suffer this same fate!", which gives the feeling of closure as a punishment directed at people. Finally, it also leaves an actual searchable and discoverable presence on the site, that people will argue "This should be allowed it's a fun and cool question" or stuff. Arguments that many find tiring to repeat after so many years.

For every person that could've seen a question be closed and thought "Oh maybe I shouldn't do this", there's probably a person or twelve that read the rules on the site and saw the rules and figured "Oh maybe I shouldn't do this". This is a speculative and reaching statement on my part but my point is that there's a lot of approaches that different systems can use to serve as signals. Other systems do this sort of "This is a bad idea don't do this", but we don't here, we figure that rules and guidelines should be a better signal for this stuff. In both speculative cases the idea is someone has to browse the site and see *something* that tells them what they shouldn't do. Ours focuses on not making examples of people. That way we can continue to keep tools functioning in the ways they do to keep the sites clean and you don't need to think about things like "Well *which* questions do we think we need to keep on the castle ramparts this time?". Deletion is just simpler and the direct design intent of the system.

Comment: With regards to things like "if you get enough posts deleted you get punished by a post ban, that's punitive!" - that's not closure and deletion being punitive. The punitive action is you getting hit by a post ban, which is done through a demonstrated behavior of repeatedly providing posts that are not received well or belong on the site. The deletion itself is not a punishment action and is not meant as one, even if it's signal in history to take effect later.